# Echo Menu located in primary navigation

Tags: menus

I have googled a lot looking for echoing main menu of primary navigation in wordpress but I did not found anything.
DO anyone has an idea how to do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp_get_nav_menu_items https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/ function to get your menu items in the form of an array , you can pass any of Menu ID, slug, name, or object in wp_get_nav_menu_items function.

```
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$main_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($locations['primary']);
print_r($main_menu);
```

Comment: I want to get the menu in primary navigation (by position) not by id

Comment: I have updated the above code, you can use it to get menu items for primary position.